# How can I get higher resolution brain image slices?

Tags: image3d

When using an expression like

```
EntityValue[
  Entity["AnatomicalFunctionalConcept", "VisualFaceRecognition"],    
  EntityProperty["AnatomicalFunctionalConcept", "BrainImageHorizontalSlices"]]
```

to get a slice showing brain activity for certain functions. Is it possible to get a higher resolution or to request a specific size?

Of course, the slices itself are naturally very limited in resolution but the legend should be scalable?

Comment: Related, [Leslie Greengard](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/greengar/) has done significant work in [image enhancement](https://cims.nyu.edu/cmcl/nufft/NUFFT_project.html)